# This Serverless Function has crashed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, vercel

I am trying to deploy backend express app in vercel, where the server just handles a mailing api using nodemailer.

my package.json

[image: image package.json]

This is my server.js

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import { config } from "dotenv";
config()

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "100mb" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "100mb", extended: true }));
app.use(cors({credentials:true}));


const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
     service: 'gmail',
     auth: {
         user: process.env.EMAIL_USER, // Use environment variables instead of hardcoding
         pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD, // Use environment variables instead of hardcoding
}
});

function sendEmail(req, res) {
const { name, email, message } = req.body;

const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.EMAIL_USER,
    to: process.env.RECIEVER_MAIL,
    subject: `You got a message from ${name}`,
    html: `<h4>Hello, Someone Contacted you through contact Form</h4>
    <h4>Name: ${name}</h4>
    <h4>Email: ${email}</h4>
    <p>Message: ${message}</p>
    `
    ,
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({code:500, error: 'Failed to send email' });
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
        res.status(200).json({code:200,success: 'Email sent successfully' });
    }
});
}
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("This is my api running!")
})

app.post('/contact', (req, res) => {
    sendEmail(req, res);
});

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`App listening on port ${PORT}`)
})
```

This is my vercel.json

```
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
  {
    "src": "server.js",
    "use": "@now/node"
  }
],
"routes": [
  {
    "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "server.js"
  }
]
```

}

The error I am getting in logs.

Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"ReferenceError","errorMessage":"require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead\nThis file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.","stack":["ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead","This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.","    at file:///var/task/___now_launcher.js:1:18","    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)"]}
Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"ReferenceError","errorMessage":"require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead\nThis file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.","stack":["ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead","This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/var/task/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.","    at file:///var/task/___now_launcher.js:1:18","    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)"]}
Unknown application error occurred
Runtime.Unknown

Answer (score 0):

Remove "type":"module" from package json, and retry.

Comment: I am using ES6 syntax, if I remove type from package.json, the imports won't work.

Comment: do your tsconfig.json have "module": "esnext" ?

Comment: I don't have tsconfig.json in my project, the source is available [here](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/distracted-julien-2z8ktg?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A12%2C20)

Comment: create one and add "module": "esnext"

Answer (score 0):

Change your `vercel.json` to this:

```
{
"version": 2,
"builds": [
  {
    "src": "server.js",
    "use": "@vercel/node"
  }
],
"routes": [
  {
    "src": "/(.*)",
    "dest": "server.js"
  }
]
```

The [`@now/node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@now/node) command is now deprecated as of 2021 and will not receive any more updates. [`@vercel/now`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vercel/node) is now the way to go!